# Using SOAPContext in Visual Studio vb.net

Tags: vb.net, wse, wse2.0

I'm working on a form and need to use SOAPContext and DimeAttatchment. Neither classes are recognized. I tried adding 'Imports Microsoft.Web.Services2' but I get a green line and the package does not seem to be recognized. How do I get soapcontext and dimeattatchment to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those classes are from the [Web Services Enhancements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Enhancements), which was a [downloadable](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=14089) add-on for Visual Studio 2005 and .NET framework 2.0. As such, it is not supported in higher versions of Visual Studio. Instead it has been superseded by [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx). There are [workarounds](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/84299cff-5af6-4cef-8b6e-a8251df3d496/) to get it to work in later versions of Visual Studio.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to install the SOAP Toolkit.
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=19135

However this was deprecated 7 years ago, is this still the best solution for your project?